# Lambda in the procedure

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Can someone explain me what's happening with the two lambda statements in the following code?

```
(define (remove x ls)
(if (null? ls)
  '()
  (let ((h (car ls)))
    ((if (eqv? x h)
        (lambda (y) y)
        (lambda (y) (cons h y)))
     (remove x (cdr ls))))))
```

What is the 'y' in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the `if`'s condition, we're returning one or the other `lambda` and then immediately applying it (notice the double opening parentheses to the left of the `if`). The first `lambda` returns the result of calling the recursion, the second `lambda` `cons`es an element to the result of calling the recursion, either way the recursion gets called. The `y` is just the parameter name for the `lambda`s, which gets bound to the value of `(remove x (cdr ls))`. The whole thing is equivalent to this, and in fact it should be written like this, not in its current, overly complicated form:

```
(define (remove x ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (let ((h (car ls)))
        (if (eqv? x h) ; using `equal?` would be a better idea
            (remove x (cdr ls))
            (cons h (remove x (cdr ls)))))))
```